# Laptop Asus G1S NO sound from built-in speakers

Tags: 11.10

After installing 11.10 from 11.04 I do not have sound coming out from my built-in speakers when I plug in headset or other speaker it works fine but the built-in speakers won't make a noise...
I tried reinstalling system=no results
Any possible sound option does not help either.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your drivers. Open up the dashboard and search for, "Additional Drivers" afterwards launch it. From there, see if you can find your sound cards drivers. If not, than open up your Ubuntu Software Center and search for, "Gnome ALSA Sound Mixer" it's the best tool to tweak and mess with your sound settings. Hope this solves your problem, if it doesn't, seek addtional support at http://ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: ALSA does not help at all there is still no sound on built-in speakers...drivers are up to date with 11.04 worked just fine...

Answer (score 1):

After much research into drivers, a friend found the speaker issue with my G1s running Ubuntu 11.10 Gnome Classic.

Run alsamixer (the Text UI version, not the GUI version), arrow over to Auto-Mute and Disable.

Why oh why is this on as a default? And Why (oh why) is the toggle only hidden in the text version, and not available on the GUI?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to find to go to Auto-Mute and Disable? I just run the command alsamixer and used my arrows to navigate, but could not find this. Sorry if im too stupid hehe

Comment: Thanks kmarsh the sound is back...and yes WHY? is it only in available in text version...

Comment: @Sam S, when I run my 11.10 command line alsamixer, the automute is not immediately on screen, I have to use the right arrow to move over to it about two screens to the right. It is a text UI so scrolling is coarse. Auto-Mute is between Beep and CallerID on my system.