# No sound on my laptop

Tags: hda-intel

I have a panasonic toughbook cf-w8 with intel hda sound card, with a fresh install of ubuntu 11.10, I can get sound out of headphones, but not from external speaker. would appreciate step by step help to solve problem. Iam fairly new to linux. thank you

Comment: Did you check **Connector** in **Sound Settings** is not set to `Analog Headphones`?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/74624/22537) might help, Question was very similar.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `internal speakers` when you say `external speaker`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on 11.10 and 12.04. Adding the following line at the bottom of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop
```

fixed the issue on my laptop.